# How do I render an Archetypes widget in 'edit' mode in a BrowserView?

Tags: python, plone, archetypes

I would like to render Plone Archetypes widgets in 'edit' mode in a `Products.Five.browser.BrowserView` but it seems there is a lot of setup for templates in skins layers that is absent from `BrowserView`. How do I perform equivalent setup in a `BrowserView`?

The resulting form needs to `POST` to the existing Archetypes logic.

Comment: Do you just need to render it, or do you also need to validate and process the input from it when someone submits a form? If the latter, there is not really a reasonable way to do that with an Archetypes widget in a BrowserView, because Archetypes form processing is managed by CMFFormController.

Comment: I do not need to process the form any differently than CMFFormController would, if that helps.

Comment: It's murderously difficult to reuse archetypes widgets outside their macro framework. I'd give that up. What's the widget? Any reason you can't code it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer to this question as @david-glick and @stevem suggest is: don't do it. If you are going to use AT (Archetypes), use AT best practices; the closest of which are explained here:

- http://docs.plone.org/old-reference-manuals/plone_3_theming/buildingblocks/skin/templates/how-to-customise-view-or-edit-on-archetypes-content-items.html

Also as @stevem suggests, you can manually code forms in browser views if you are so inclined (but you'll need to do all the validation yourself).